# Besides syntax, is there any difference between writing an initialization method as an instance or class method?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, initialization

Here is initialization as a class method:

```
+ (instancetype)imageEditorForDocument:(ImageDocument*)imageDocument
{
   ImageEditorViewController* result = nil;
   result = [[ImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageEditorViewController"
                                                        bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

   if ( result )
   {
      result.imageDocument = imageDocument;
   }
   return result;
}
```

And here is an initialization as an instance method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithDocument:(ImageDocument *)imageDocument
{
   self = [[ImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageEditorViewController"
                                                       bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

   if( self )
   {
      self.imageDocument = imageDocument;
   }
   return self;
}
```

As far as I can tell, the only difference is that the sender doesn't need to call `alloc` when using a class initializer

But is there any other reason?

**Also, a side question** is there a name for a initializer that is a class method?
Like in `NSColor`

```
+ (NSColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_9);
```

Comment: It's called a factory method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With manual reference counting (MRC), the difference was the factory method typically returned an autoreleased instance while the instance method returned an instance that the caller now owned.

With automatic reference counting (ARC), that difference is now hidden from the calling code.

So the only difference is convenience for the caller as well as slightly more work for the author of the class to write the optional factory method.

BTW - your instance method initializer is incorrect. It should be more like this (not the proper way to set `self`):

```
- (instancetype)initWithDocument:(ImageDocument *)imageDocument
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:@"ImageEditorViewController"
                          bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

   if( self )
   {
      self.imageDocument = imageDocument;
   }

   return self;
}
```

And given this, your factory method should really be:

```
+ (instancetype)imageEditorForDocument:(ImageDocument*)imageDocument
{
   ImageEditorViewController* result = [[[self class] alloc] initWithDocument:imageDocument];

   return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks rmaddy :)  And oops my bad on the wrong code-- I actually just copy pasted the factory method and changed it to look like the instance initialization-- but overlooked that portion.  Thanks for the correction ^^

Comment: See my latest update. Your factory method was wrong too.

Comment: The instance initializer doesn't exist in our current code, though.
So you're recommending that I create the instance initializer method, and then change the factory method to call that?

Comment: But I guess at that point there'd be no reason for the factory method if the instance initializer exists?

Comment: That's the standard pattern. The factory method typically is just a convenience for calling the instance initializer. Just like the ``NSColor` example you gave. It basically avoids the need to call `alloc`. In the days of ARC, there is much less need for these convenience factory methods.

Comment: Though Lasse makes a nice point in his answer. The factory method can be a lot more than just calling alloc and the instance initializer. It can do caching or return singletons or lots of other improvements.

Comment: I commented on his question, but I guess I"m unclear why the caching or singleton-returning cannot be done in an instance initializer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a major difference. If you implement a factory method (class method) you could for example choose to return an already existing instance of your object (e.g. from some sort of cache) instead of creating a new instance. Imagine you have a class `Country` which is expensive to initialize. Hence, write the following factory method that looks up the cache first and only if it does not find the country it creates a new object:

```
+(instancetype) countryForCountryCode: (NSString *)countryCode 
{
    Country *country = ... // ask our "CountryCache" if we already have a cached instance of the country
    if (!country) {
        country = [[Country alloc] init];
        // Here you would also set up the new Country object, or even write a "private" initializer
        // You would also add the new instance to the cache here
    }
    return country;
}
```

On the other hand, when you choose a "conventional" initializer the caller will always have created a fresh instance via `alloc` before your initializer gets called, and you'll have no way of returning a cached object instead.

Lastly I just remembered that I personally use factory methods whenever I deal with persistent objects (if not using CoreData). So, if I want to get a new object from the database I usually implement a factory method called "load". And to actually create a new record in the database I would implement another factory method named "create". If you would use initializers here it would become very confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The concept sounds correct, but I'm not totally there.  What's stopping you from returning a cached object in an instance initializer?  Before calling `[super init]`, couldn't a check be made, and just return the cached object if it exists?

Comment: What's stopping me would be that in an instance initializer I am already "in" the new instance that the caller has created with `alloc`. Practically speaking I would need to assign some other object to `self`, which is not allowed.

Comment: But wait, doesn't that happen with any custom initializer?  `self = [super init]`, `if( self ) {}`, `return self;`.  `self` is being assigned to the object from `[super init]`?

Comment: Not really. Maybe reading [Object Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW58) helps to understand it better, but in short `[super init]` will still return `self` unless it fails in which case it returns `nil`.

Comment: And to make it even more complicated I just figured that you actually CAN set `self` to some other arbitrary object. I was sure this wasn't possible but obviously it is. Having said that, I'd never implement such a behavior. It just feels wrong...